# How to access firebase user in getServerSideProps after (new) Firebase Auth update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Specifically [this part of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/nextjs#optional_integrate_with_firebase_authentication) underlines:

> The Express res.locals object will optionally contain an
> authenticated Firebase App instance (firebaseApp) and the currently
> signed-in user (currentUser). This can be accessed in
> getServerSideProps

Above makes sense, I would find a firebase app and user instance in `context.res.locals` in `getServerSideProps`, but it's undefined when doing it in code.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  // Returns undefined
  console.log(context.res.locals);
  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

Then the docs follow with:

> The authenticated Firebase App name is provided on the route query
> (__firebaseAppName). This allows for manual integration while in
> context:

```
 // get the authenticated Firebase App
  const firebaseApp = getApp(useRouter().query.__firebaseAppName);
```

This is the bit that I find confusing? What does this mean and where do I put the code snippet?
I'm guessing the second part is needed for the first part to work

Comment: I'm also seeing the same problem. I'm not able to see the initialised app at all in the emulator environment.